# default only works for 8 and 9. after that it uses the first number and treats it as a a 1,2,3

Tags: c++

default isn't working except for numbers 8 and 9.
10 and above it uses the first integer its treats it as a case completely ignoring the second number after it. please help

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
     char day;
        cout << " Enter day of the week " << endl;
        cin >> day;
        switch (day)
   {  
        case '1' : case '6' : case '7' :
           cout << "weekend";
            break;

    case '2' : case '4' :
        cout << "going to C++ Class";
        break;

    case '3' : case '5' :
        cout << "studying for C++ Class";
        break;

    default :
        cout << "invalid day number";


}


    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Hint: try changing `char day` to `int day` (and the char literals to ints, thanks @Matti) and see if that helps...

Comment: Then he'll also need to change those char literals in the cases to plain integers.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
char day;
cin>>day;
```

It will accept only one character from input. You should declare day as integer and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

You're only storing one character in your `day` variable because it's declared as a `char`.  Change it to an `int`, and change the cases in your switch statements to `int` values.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int day;
    cout << " Enter day of the week " << endl;
    cin >> day;

    switch (day)
    {  
        case 1:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            cout << "weekend";
            break;
        case 2:
        case 4:
            cout << "going to C++ Class";
            break;
        case 3:
        case 5:
            cout << "studying for C++ Class";
            break;
        default :
            cout << "invalid day number";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is storing the input in a `char`.

Since you store `day` as a char, it is only big enough to store the first character of whatever the input is. When you input `1` (or `2`, or `3`, etc) that's fine, since there *is* only one character of input. When you input a number with more than one digit, only the first character can be stored - for example, if you enter `10`, then there's only room to store the `1`.

To fix this, you should use a more appropriate data type for `day`. Using an `int` or something similar is probably best, as that will give you plenty of room for large values. So, in other words, change `char day;` to `int day;`.

If you do so though, you'll need to change the values in your `case` statements to match - since you're no longer comparing characters, you'll need to change them to ints too (e.g. change `'0'` to just `0`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 char day;
    cout << " Enter day of the week " << endl;
    cin >> day;
```

Your code says to read one character from standard input. If that's not what you want do, change the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful while you decide on the data type of the variable, since every data type comes with its inherent properties. Like everyone pointed out here, you need to change data type from 'char' to 'int'.